# Objective-C - Parsing a CSV into a array

Tags: cocoa-touch, arrays

How would I parse a CSV into an array. Its only a one column spread sheet I converted into an CSV so it shouldn't be too hard right?

Any way how do I do this?

Answer (score 12):

Use a proper CSV parser such as https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

```
new_array *new_obj = [csv_array componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: This doesn't handle quoted values that may themselves contain a comma.

Comment: really bad :( this approach don't manage ALL the options like @Greg Malefic says