# How can I read .txt files split the info and save in a kind of array list in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm a complete noob in Objective C and i need help to do this things.
1) this is the format of one line in my .txt file:   00000000000022378540,20121101,061153,20121101,061256,00000000105,00000000000022894859,SLHO,L,03,00000000116,201211,PRI4,      ,      ,HONDU,MLFON

2) I read my .txt file on this way:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"Users/carlosmedina/Desktop/CDRs.txt"];
NSString *content =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSetnewlineCharacterSet]];
```

I don't understand this language a lot but i need to read that information, save it in array list 
parsed by coma (,)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286254/objective-c-parsing-a-csv-into-a-array

Comment: what should it do? what does it do right? what does it do wrong?

Comment: The program should read the file line per line, split the information of the line by coma creating a list of  new objects that contains this information. for example with this fields:
Object 1 {
00000000000022378540
20121101
061153
20121101
etc.. etc.. etc..
}

i need to get the list and get one object like this
list.get(1).getElement1() or
list.get(1).getElement2()
etc.. etc.. etc..

Comment: hahahahah i think that i'm going to build in java because is very difficult objective c

Comment: You have what's referred to as a CSV (comma-separated values) file.  Add that to your Google searches.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *myList = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]

This will return an array when your list is comma separated.